# Replication issues after restart - SYNC node thinks that it is MAIN

Tags: memgraphdb

I have Memgraph 2.2.1 (Docker using memgraph-platform image)

I'm setting up a replication scenario. I have three instances:
While testing replication I created multiple instances:

Insta1: `docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 3000:3000 -v mg_lib:/var/lib/memgraph memgraph/memgraph-platform`

Insta2: `docker run -it -p 7688:7687 -p 3001:3000 -v mg_lib2:/var/lib/memgraph memgraph/memgraph-platform`

Insta3: `docker run -it -p 7689:7687 -p 3002:3000 -v mg_lib3:/var/lib/memgraph memgraph/memgraph-platform`

I demoted Insta2 and Insta3 to replicas and registered them from the main (Insta1) in `SYNC` mode.  I shut down Insta3, brought it back up with the same IP address. Insta3 claims that it has `MAIN` role.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. After restart replica forgets it's status and restarts as main instance. This is a bug, and it is being handled at https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/pull/791.